# How to implement lazy db data fetching using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, lazy-loading, junit4

Before describing my problem I want to let you know that I am new in Spring.

So here I just put my sample code what I do to fetch data from db using JDBCTemplate :

```
    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/mypc/Downloads/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/demo/databases/toursdb;create=true");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from " + tableName);
    dataSource.getConnection().close();
    System.out.println(rows);
```

So here I put my whole resultset in Map and then return it. Problem is It throws java heap memory exception for large dataset(As I mentioned above posted code is for sample).

Now I change this implementation using RowCallbackHandler().

So my modified code is now

```
            SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby:C:/Users/mypc/Downloads/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/demo/databases/toursdb;create=true");
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(200);
            jdbcTemplate.query("select * from " + tableName, new RowCallbackHandler() {
                public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                    Map<String, Object> rowInMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        rowInMap.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
                    }
                    System.out.println(rowInMap);
                }
            });
            dataSource.getConnection().close();
```

But problem is how to use rowcallbackhandler method from another method from another class which will consume data lazyly and obviously it should be thread safe. It will be used for JUnit test.

Comment: `consume data lazily` I do not think this means what you think it means.  What you seem to want is batching, i.e. the consuming code retrieves data in batches of some fixed size (e.g. 20, 50, 100 whatever) and processes it in chunks.

Comment: yes exactly I want to filledup my map with 20 data and then process it again bck to resultset retrive part and it will fill up the map with next 20 data

Comment: I say again, look into batching with jdbc templates

Comment: I look into this but I observe that it is used for update my requirement is retriving data from db not updating the db.

Comment: paginating may be a term with more hits on google.

Comment: @taylor thanks for your suggestion I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling jdbc driver to fetch rows by 200 and 200. Here is the explanation of Statement class java doc.

```
/**
     * Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should
     * be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for
     * <code>ResultSet</code> objects genrated by this <code>Statement</code>.
     * If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored.
     * The default value is zero.
     *
     * @param rows the number of rows to fetch
     * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs,
     * this method is called on a closed <code>Statement</code> or the
     *        condition  <code>rows >= 0</code> is not satisfied.
     * @since 1.2
     * @see #getFetchSize
     */
```

You don't tell a lazy loading or filtering to your query, you fetch whole table. Easiest way is using where condition to filter your records or use a pagination feature. 
For oracle you can add " where rownum < 200" to your query.
Spring jdbc is based on fetching records, collecting inside a collection and returning. So when you receive your List this means whole data is retrieved from database and statement is closed. You can process your record inside RowCallbackHandler class however during your process the database statement and resultset will be open.

Comment: As per your suggestion if I put rownum for oracle or top for sql server I can not fetch all data but I need all data to check with my expected one.

Comment: so you have to filter your data with where clause in your sql. Beside oracle rownum doesn't guarantee to fetch the same data each time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but is there any way to return chunk of map and validate over this and if not found the desired result again call it and return the next chunk of map from the same resultset it is like yield return.